# In bash, how to split or merge a file between different machines?

Tags: linux, performance, shell, unix, client-server

Actually, I have a server and many clients.These clients each have its own config file.Server will get all the clients' config files, and then merge them into one file, then works.Sometimes, client will get server's merged file then modify its part, send it back.Like this pic:

[image]

Well, I have tried one way to do this.

Each client keep a own split config file and update it. When a client modify its piece, then try to get all the clients' pieces and merge them into one file.Then send this file to the server.

```
cat split.1 >> all.config
cat split.2 >> all.config
cat split.3 >> all.config
```

When client syncs the config file, then it gets the all.config from server, then split it into pieces by "split flag"...

I think it's a really supid way, but it works.Are there any other more beautiful ways to realise this need?

Comment: Why does the server depend on the clients' config files? This seems like an awkward design in the first place.

Comment: I agree this is a poor way to do things, however, a network mount (nfs for example) would not be out of order here. Let the filesystem do the state-keeping, that's what they're for. Adrian is right; you should definitely re-think the architecture you have.